# How to build classes structure correctly

Tags: php, oop

I have this class

```
class Base
{
  // This class contains a lot of private method which are using inside this class
  private function CreateRequest()
  {
    //using curl to send request
  }
}

class API_CALLS extend Base
{
  //Here i want to create a static class to make API calls to server, but i need to use create request method from base class
  static public get_name()
  {
    $params = array();
    $this->CreateRequest($params); // i know this causes the error
  }
}
```

What is the best way to create a class structure in my case?

Comment: i think the function CreateRequest in class Base should be protected

Answer (score -1):

you must know the meaning of "private","static","$this"  in class.

```
class Base
{
   protected static function CreateRequest()
   {
    //using curl to send request
   }
}

class API_CALLS extends Base
{

    static function get_name()
    {
    $params = array();
    self::CreateRequest($params); 
    }
}
```